# Bash backslash escaping issue when using read

Tags: bash, readline

I have some XSL spitting out samba paths on stdout.  I am iterating these paths to locate them on their mountpoints on disk, so have something along the lines of:

```
while read src dst ; do
    ...
done < <(xsltproc - file.xml <<XSL
...
XSL
)
```

Now, I can trivially solve the problem by performing the path escaping either in the XSL stylesheet or by using sed.  However, I am curious from a bash perspective, how to solve the problem.  Here is a working example of the problem:

```
a='\\a\b\c\d\e'
ecyo $a
\\a\b\c\d\e
echo ${a//\\//}
//a/b/c/d/e
b=$a
echo $b
\\a\b\c\d\e
b=$(echo $a)
echo $b
\\a\b\c\d\e
```

That's all fine, does exactly what I expect it to do.  This is where bash gets a bit funny:

```
read b < <(echo $a)
echo $b
\abcde
echo ${b//\\//}
/abcde
```

As you can see, `read` has stripped all of the unescaped backslashes when it read them in, so the directory information gets lost.

Answer (score 3):

Reading the bash manual, it seems this works just fine:

```
read -r b < <(echo $a)
```

The `-r` flag tells read not to treat backslashes as escape characters.